# Need help coming with Wh- questions that shows possession "of the" in answer

Tags: wh-questions

I require help or could use some examples of Wh- questions that shows possession to an object in the answer using "of the."

I do understand the use "of the" when it comes to possession but I am having issues coming up with a proper question.

So I want to know the Wh- question that has answers like

> They are the wings of the plane" or
>
> "It is the cover of the book"

Comment: What is the Wh-question those are answers to?

Comment: Yes, what would be good Wh-questions for those answers.

Comment: I wonder if you're looking for something like: 'what are they the wings of'? It sounds clunky, but you can't say 'whose wings are they?' because a plane isn't a person. If you just happened to see a pile of separate plane wings in a factory you might ask: what do these belong to? Or even: what are these? Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Some question words: who/whom/whose, what, when, where, why, how.

Who, whom, and whose are used where the answer is a person (or anthropomorphized being or concept).

> Whose book is it?
>
> It is his book.

A very formal question:

> To whom does the book belong?
>
> The book belongs to Jim.

A less formal question:

> Who owns the book?
>
> It's Jim's book.

What is used for non-anthropomorphized things:

> What are the wings part of?
>
> The wings are part of the plane.

Sometimes where is used to ask who or what has something.

> Where are the wings?
>
> The wings are on the plane.
>
> Where's my coat?
>
> Jack has your coat.

Why and how are unlikely to be used to get the original post's answers.

Answer (score 0):

One very common use of the "possessive" in English grammar is to indicate ownership, either informal or formal. **That is John's car** can be used to mean that John has legal title to the car.

Another very common use of the grammatical possessive is to indicate that two specific people are related in a specific way. **That old woman is the slim woman's grandmother" and **That slim woman is the old woman's granddaughter** mean the same thing, and neither means that either woman is a slave. Those sentences indicate that the two women form a specific instance of a general social relationship.

A third common use of the grammatical possessive is to indicate that one thing is a part of a whole. **That car's engine is in its rear** or **The engine of that car is located in the rear of the car** both mean that a physical part of the car, namely the engine, can be found in a locational part of the car. They might be the answer to the question "Where is there room for an engine in that car."